# Id Undefined cuando intento obtener el parámetro enviado a una ruta desde un componente

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Estoy aprendiendo React JS, todo iba perfecto hasta que llegué al tema de las rutas, y es que cuando intento obtener el parametro enviado al componente por medio de `this.props.match.params.id` este me arroja indefinido, y he buscado pero no encuentro solución.

archivo `App.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import { Student } from "./pages/Student";
import { AddStudent } from "./pages/AddStudent";
import { EditStudent }  from "./pages/EditStudent";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Student />} />
        <Route path="/add-student" element={<AddStudent />} />
        <Route path="/edit-student/:id" element={<EditStudent />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Archivo `EditStudent`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

class EditStudent extends Component {
  state = {
    name: "",
    course: "",
    email: "",
    phone: "",
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const student_id = this.props.match.params.id;
    const res = await axios.get(
      `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/edit-student/${student_id}`
    );

    if (res.data.status === 200) {
      this.setState({
        name: res.data.student.name,
        course: res.data.student.course,
        email: res.data.student.email,
        phone: res.data.student.phone,
      });
    }
  }
  handleInput = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };
  updateStudent = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const student_id = this.props.match.params.id;
    const res = await axios.put(
      `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/update-student/${student_id}`,
      this.state
    );

    if (res.data.status === 200) {
      console.log(res.data.message);
      this.setState({
        name: "",
        course: "",
        email: "",
        phone: "",
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12">
              <div className="card">
                <div className="card-header">
                  <h4>
                    Edit Student
                    <Link to={"/"} className="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-end">
                      Back
                    </Link>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div className="card-body">
                  <form onSubmit={this.updateStudent}>
                    <div className="form-group mb-3">
                      <label>Student Name</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        name="name"
                        onChange={this.handleInput}
                        className="form-control"
                        value={this.state.name || ""}
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group mb-3">
                      <label>Student Course</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        name="course"
                        onChange={this.handleInput}
                        className="form-control"
                        value={this.state.course || ""}
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group mb-3">
                      <label>Student Email</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        name="email"
                        onChange={this.handleInput}
                        className="form-control"
                        value={this.state.email || ""}
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group mb-3">
                      <label>Student Phone</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        name="phone"
                        onChange={this.handleInput}
                        className="form-control"
                        value={this.state.phone || ""}
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group mb-3">
                      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                        Update Student
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export { EditStudent };
```

Answer (score 0):

Parece que se esta usando la versión 6 del react router, esta forma de obtener `URL params` ya es obsoleta `router v6`:

```
const student_id = this.props.match.params.id;
```

Otro problema es, que se esta armando el componente `EditStudent` en su forma `class`.

#### Hook useParams y función intermediaria para Class Component

Ahora, para tener acceso a los URL params de debe usar el hook `useParams()`, pero el componente class no tiene acceso a los Hooks, entonces se puede crear una función intermediaria `Auxroute`:

```
<Route path="/edit-student/:id" element={<Auxroute />} />
```

La cual pasará el hook `useParams` como `props` al componente `EditStudent`:

```
const Auxroute = () => <EditStudent params={useParams()}/>
```

Se consume de esta forma:

```
class EditStudent extends Component {
//...
componentDidMount() {
        const id = this.props.params.id;
        console.log("id:",id);
  }
//...
}
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.